# Деление сети класса C на подсети

Tags: сеть

Как разделить сеть класса C на 7 подсетей,соединенных одним маршрутизатором. Если не используем первую и последнюю подсети, то взяв маску /28, получим 16 подсетей, что много.

Comment: а если немного [погуглить](https://www.google.ru/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+ip+%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9) первая же ссылка поможет выбрать необходимую маску сети, Вам может подойти `255.255.255.224`(/27)

Comment: а последняя и первая подсети не используются?

Comment: *Если не используем первую и последнюю подсети* - а это обязательное условие?! из текста вопроса не понятно, мои познания ограничиваются тем что сети можно разбить при помощи *масок*, вариантов у Вас собственно не так и много либо разбить на 8 подсетей либо на 16., Вы можете разбить на 16 подсетей, и просто не использовать не нужные Вам, ничего страшного в этом нет

Comment: @Fred А почему вы не хотите использовать первую и последнюю подсети ? Ничего запрещающего или хотя бы предписывающего резервировать первую и последнюю _подсети_ не существует.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

из подсети с длиной префикса `24` бита (в терминах устаревшей [классовой адресации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) — «сеть класса це») можно получить (на выбор):

- две подсети с длиной префикса `25` бит
- четыре подсети с длиной префикса `26` бит
- восемь подсетей с длиной префикса `27` бит
- шестнадцать подсетей с длиной префикса `28` бит
- и так далее

вам вполне подойдёт разбиение на подсети с длиной префикса `27` бит — одну из восьми подсетей вы вполне вольны не использовать.